# Concat 2 variables and use that variable to get value from property file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a property file with below properties,

```
apache_ip=127.0.0.1
apache_user=root
```

Now in my shell script i did something like below,

```
source $1
service=$2 #$2=apache
variable=${service}_ip
serviceIP=${variable}
echo ${serviceIP}
```

I want to get the output as **127.0.0.1**, but the output was **apache_ip**

I have tried different combination but it dint work. How to concat two variable and use that variable to get the value from property file.

Comment: What is `service=$2 ($2=apache)` supposed to do?

Comment: I am passing the value of service as argument. First argument is property file. Second argument is apache,

Comment: Argument to what?

Comment: argument to shell script. eg, sudo sh test.sh sample.properties apache.

Comment: Ah, is `($2=apache)` supposed to be a comment on that line? `service=$2   # $2 == apache`?

Comment: it is a comment only :( updated the question

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this? I assume you are using bash.

```
service="apache"
apache_ip="127.0.0.1"
variable="${service}_ip"
ip="${!variable}"
echo "$ip"
```

which prints 127.0.0.1.

Look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for more information on shell parameter expansion in bash shell.

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point (!), and
>   parameter is not a nameref, it introduces a level of variable
>   indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest
>   of parameter as the name of the variable; this variable is then
>   expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution,
>   rather than the value of parameter itself. This is known as indirect
>   expansion. If parameter is a nameref, this expands to the name of the
>   variable referenced by parameter instead of performing the complete
>   indirect expansion.

Comment: your solution solves my problem. I have include ip="${!variable}" in the script and it worked. Can you please tell me what is the use of not(!) operation in this did the trick. ?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get the values from the config file, you can use `grep`:

```
configfile=$1
service=$2 
serviceIP=$(grep "^${service}_ip=" configfile|cut -d= -f2-)
echo "serviceIP=${serviceIP}"
```

You can do about the same when the configfile has been sourced:

```
serviceIP=$(set | grep "^${service}_ip=" |cut -d= -f2-)
echo "serviceIP=${serviceIP}"
```